# How to find fourth and fifth regression coefficients in R?

Tags: r, regression

I would like to compute `5` regression coefficients.I searched thru Internet but I did not find anything for this.
my data:

```
    y=c(2,13,0.4,5,8,10,13)
    x=c(2,13,0.004,5,8,1,13)
    z=c(2,3,0.004,15,8,10,1)
```

normal equation:

```
   y=a1x+a2z+a3
```

x, z, independent variables, y is the dependent variable, and a1 a3, and a2 are the parameters of the model.

normal fit for this equation::

```
       fit=lm(y~x+z)
```

but my equation looks like:

```
      y=((a1x+a2z+a3)^a4)+a5
```

my question is how we can find the other parameters of this model `a4` and `a5`(constant) in the equation shown above.what shall I use in R to find them?

Comment: Have a look at `?nls`

Comment: I guess this question would be better for http://stats.stackexchange.com/
as it is a statistical/model-based question and no programming question

Comment: sacvf, the model equation you give *is* nonlinear.

Comment: Examples in `nls` show how to fit your formula. Have you tried that? More or less you have to replace `=` with `~`, add data, initial parameters and hope the default algorithm is able to crunch through the optimization. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about the following using the `optim`?

```
f <- function(p){
          sum((y - (p[1]*x+p[2]*z+p[3])^p[4]+p[5])^2)
     }

p <- optim(rep(.5, 5), f)$par
p
[1]  3.5539397  0.8423521  0.1872422  0.6287906 -0.1863242
```

So, `a5` is `-0.1863242`. The fitted values look as follows:

```
plot(seq_along(y), y)
lines((p[1]*x+p[2]*z+p[3])^p[4]+p[5])
```

[image]

Comment: In order to minimize the residual sum of squares. These are differences between your response and the fitted values.

Comment: They are the starting values of the five parameters for the optimization

Comment: The resulting estimates can differ in dependence of the starting values. This is the shortcoming of the nonlinear estimation. You can control the number of iterations using the argument `maxit`

Comment: You have forgotten to include the `p` as an argument to your function